# Randomly split a data table and make output files in R

Tags: r, split, data.table, write.table

I want to randomly split a data table into n number of outputs; then I want to write.table those outputs for each list. So, in test I want to write a file for each list within test.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(100)

dt <- data.table(x=rnorm(1000))

n <- 10 # number of data sets

# randomly splits dt into n number of outputs
test <- split(dt, sample(1:n, nrow(dt), replace=T))

# writing tables for each sublist within test
# write.table(test)
# names <- paste0("output", n, ".txt", sep="")
```

Comment: maybe `dt[, fwrite(.SD, paste0(.BY, ".csv")), sample(1:n, nrow(dt), replace=TRUE)]`

Comment: You can loop over the names of 'test' `lapply(names(test), function(nm) fwrite(test[[nm]], paste0("output", nm, ".txt')))`

Comment: Any way to not include the header of each list in the output files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `fwrite` as it is a `data.table` and is much faster

```
library(data.table)
lapply(names(test), function(nm) fwrite(test[[nm]], paste0("output", nm, ".txt")))
```

The `header` 'x' is the column name and if we need some custom formatting, it can be done with `cat`

```
lapply(names(test), function(nm) 
      cat(test[[nm]][[1]], file = paste0("output", nm, ".txt"), sep = "\n"))
```

Or as @chinsoon12 mentioned in the comments, specify `col.names = FALSE` (by default it is TRUE in `fwrite`)

```
lapply(names(test), function(nm) fwrite(test[[nm]],
          paste0("output", nm, ".txt"), col.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: This may be nitpicky but is there a way to not include the header within each list?

Comment: @ConnorMurray. Did you meant the column names not to be included?

Comment: Output1.txt for instance, the first row is " x ". Is there a way to not have this within each list?

Comment: @ConnorMurray It is the column name of the data.table.  If you want to store it without the column name, then you may do with `cat` i.e. `lapply(names(test), function(nm) cat(test[[nm]][[1]], file = paste0("output", nm, ".txt"), sep = "\n"))`

Comment: you can use `col.names=FALSE` as an arg to `fwrite`

Comment: This is all great, is there any way to control the number of samples per list? Say I want to have 100 samples per list? This may be very useful for other people. Thanks

Comment: @ConnorMurray  You may use `replicate` and specify the `n` with number of samples, not sure what you wanted

Comment: I was thinking something like: replicate(10, sample(dt, 100, replace= TRUE))

Comment: @ConnorMurray. and specify `simplify = FALSE` to return a `list`

Answer (score 2):

You could do :

```
lapply(seq_along(test), function(x) 
       write.table(test[[x]], file = paste0('output', x, '.txt')))
```